# C# instance object

Tags: c#

Can I make like

`Form1 form1 = new Form1();`

Without losing data
I mean like there is 2 textboxes which is filled and this form was closed and opened another Form2
And I want access data from this 2 textboxes but when I made

`Form1 form1 = new Form1();`

I'm losing data (like is empty)

````
// LogInForm id returner
public partial class LogInForm : Form
{
public int IdReturner()
{
var idFinder = (from x in context.Users where x.EmailAddress == txtBoxEmail.Text select x.Id).FirstOrDefault();
            LoginViewer.UserReturner(Convert.ToString(idFinder));
            return idFinder;
        }
}
// Here is where I need store id
public partial class ProductAddToDatabase : UserControl
{
private void btnSave_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            model.ProductName = txtBoxProductName.Text;
            model.ProductPrice = Convert.ToDouble(txtBoxProductPrice.Text);
            model.ProductAmount = Convert.ToInt32(txtBoxProductQuantity.Text);
            var id = loginForm.IdReturner();
            using (var context = new ProductContext())
            {
                context.Products.Add(model);
                context.SaveChanges();
                MessageBox.Show("Product added sucesfully "+ id, "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                Clear();
            }
        }
}```
````

Comment: Not sure I understand the question since, `Form1 form1 = new Form1(); Form1 form1 = new Form1();` isnt allowed in the same scope. Please edit your question with a [mcve]. But, typically, if you want access to historically (saved) data, you'd use some type of persistence layer, like a database, not in-memory objects, which are completely lost when you dereference and GC the previous instances

Comment: You are creating a *new* Form1, so why should it keep values from the old one?

Comment: I have LogInForm which I use to login user. And I want to use email from textbox to find id and use that id while storing information about products in database. So every user has their own data. But when I make
`LogInForm loginForm = new LogInForm();`

Textboxes goes empty

Comment: Show us your ACTUAL code so we can understand what FORMS are involved and which form creates which other one.  It makes a huge difference.  So is `LogInForm` creating an instance of `Form1`?...and you are trying to get the values out of LogInForm inside Form1?

Comment: `var id = loginForm.IdReturner();`  So we assume this code is in `Form1`?  You're still not showing us which form created which and displayed the other...

Comment: Okay, now you've added a USERCONTROL, `ProductAddToDatabase` into the mix.  WHERE is that UserControl contained?...in `LogInForm`, `Form1`, or somewhere else?

Comment: I have to get id into user control not in other Form

Comment: "I have to get id into user control not in other Form"  That doesn't clear anything up at all.  Which form, be EXPLICIT, contains this UserControl?  Your inability to accurately describe your setup and answer questions is preventing you from getting an answer...

Answer (score 2):

`new Form1();`, creates a [new](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/new-operator) instance of type `Form1` it's not returning an existing one.

If you are trying to access information from an existing `Form1` in `Form2` you would want to cache the instance of `Form1`, you are trying to access, somewhere e.g.:

```
// Keep in mind that this is just an example!
public class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }

    // trying to access the text in this textbox from Form2
    public TextBox textbox1;

    public static Form1 Instance;
}

public class Form2 : Form
{
    public string TextInForm1Textbox1
    {
        get
        {
            return Form1.Instance.textbox1.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well, before you open new forms you need persist your data in another variable like this:

```
var form1 = new Form();
var form1Data = form1;
form1 = new Form();
```

this is not a good practice and your question is not well structured, but basically you would need to do this.

Comment: Wasn't it makes new Form before giving the values? because of 'new Form()'